# How to declare string > string > number structure in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to declare a useState, but I do not clealy understand TypeScript. What should I write in place of `XXXXXX`. I have a strict JSON with string > string > number structure and I will populate `selectedLayoutItemIds`  from it. Top level id is called `eventTimeId`, 2nd level I would call `layoutItemId`, 3rd level `count`. Would you help a bit?

```
const [selectedLayoutItemIds, setSelectedLayoutItemIds] = useState<
    { [eventTimeId: string]: XXXXXX } | undefined
  >();
```

Comment: I think you need to write `{ [key: string]: XXXXXX }`, you mustn't "name" the key

Answer (score 0):

You only have to describe the structure of the data as you would do in a regular json and the 1st & 2nd level keys will be treated as strings:

```
interface LayoutItemIds { 
    eventTimeId: {
        layoutItemId: {
            count: number;
        }
    } 
}

const [selectedLayoutItemIds, setSelectedLayoutItemIds] = useState<LayoutItemIds | undefined>();
```

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBEFMDMEsDtYBdYHt6ldUSCeAHSAOgCg9DQAZAQ11QFckBJJSAWyYBMBnUAXlABvUCVBjQkAG6R4SACqw2kLgC4ho8ZoA2tBs1YdOawRs1nQAYway18emwBGkAE4BuU2YC%20HzyN8AfUHp4ThgESE4SEhBQAFVuSExscmISK3huJFAdOkYWdi5uNRpc-QKefnVNAAKpGXlFZSMq82zdPINVFtbxK2CkNQBmD01vUZJvDSA) to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I declared a new interface:

```
export type LayoutItemIdsWithAvailability = {
  [layoutItemId: string]: number;
};
```

and used here:

```
const [selectedLayoutItemIds, setSelectedLayoutItemIds] = useState<
  { [eventTimeId: string]: LayoutItemIdsWithAvailability } | undefined
>();
```